# How to always expand the WordPress custom field (back-end)

Tags: wordpress

I am talking about Wordpress back-end here,
How to hide the wordpress collapse/expand button and keep it always expand
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine to me, but from what I saw you are loading the script.js (http://clipdisplayserver.de/wordpress/wp-content/themes/clip/js/script.js)  file twice in the page. Maybe that's causing your problem.